# What is the fastest way to insert a large amount of records into a SQL Server DB?

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert

I need to insert millions of records being read from disk into SQL server. I am parsing these from a file on one machine, in what is a single-threaded process.

Ideally I would want it to perform well if the SQL server is local or remote. It has to be done programatically in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fastest way is using SSIS with parallel reads, NUMA affinitizes clients, partitions writes and switch all partitions into a single table at the end. This will load you [more than 2 TB per hour](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlperf/archive/2008/02/27/etl-world-record.aspx).

If you have a suitable text file then probably bulk copy utility.

If you want to insert from your process, then you can either use the [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver.aspx) but you have to present the data as an IDataReader, or you can use straigh SqlCommand inserts. With later, if you batch inserts commits, you'll achieve a good trhoughput. The usual bottleneck is the log flush on single statement commits.

Comment: I am so glad I didn't try answer this question... I'm sure its not practical in his situation (my guess is he'll end up using bulk copy) but wow, quite the "fastest" way there...

Comment: It's tru that is not 'practical', but is useful info as a reference to know what is possible. Once you see how the pro's do it, you can find innovative ways to apply it to the task at hand.

Comment: Followup Question. Any idea if just a SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer on a single thread is sufficient to hit a bottleneck, or would it be better to put these on multiple threads.

Comment: Bulk copy operations are mutually exclusive as they acquire table level locks. Multiple threads can only write bulk copy into separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try [bulk copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a.aspx). You can use the [SqlBulkCopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to write a little app to read your data in memory and load it into SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) utility is lightning fast and configurable. While it is a standalone utility, it runs from the command line and can certainly be summoned from c#.

Comment: The main issue I see with this is that I need to read in the data from disk, parse it, and then write it out to a file, and then calling bcp. Anything to go straight from memory->sql?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your input file format (1) it is suited for bulk copy, so, use it, (2) it is not suited for bulk copy or you need extra processing/checks/etc.. on the server-side ; so DO jump in with multi-threaded inserts loops, commit every 1000 row or more, and possibly use array inserts